# Failed assertions inside for loop is not failing the Gatling scenario

Tags: scala, assert, gatling

I'm trying to validate whether error messages returned by API are proper or not.
So, I stored all local error message strings in HashMap `errorMessage`

```
.doIf(errorMessages.size()>1) { 
    exec(session => {
   assert(ResponseJSON.contains(errorMessages.get("errorMessage1")))
   for ((k,v)<- errorMessages){
      assert(ResponseJSON.contains(v))
    }
}
```

I could see the error on console as

```
hook-3' crashed with 'java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed', forwarding to the next one
```

But, the Gatling scenarios are not failing here, what is I'm missing ?

Comment: If you're going to use `.size()`, shouldn't you be testing for `.size() > 0` ? - or better yet, use `.nonEmpty`

Comment: `.size()` will give me size, I want to check exact string match

Comment: There are too many things that can go wrong with this snippet. One can only guess. Can you post a small runnable equivalent example?

Comment: Hey @NetanelRabinowitz It would be great help buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an exitHereIfFailed to exit the scenario.

Comment: Thanks @niharika_neo, but it will abruptly stop execution at first failure only. I want my execution to be continued though some scenario get failed in between.

Comment: In that case, will exitBlockOnFail help?

Comment: let me give a try